# How to Retrieve all mails inbox content from my domain

Tags: java, php, programming-languages

If i have domain as xxxxdomain.com and i have number of mail's such as mail1@domain.com, mail2@domain.com and so on. Now i need to retrieve all mail inbox content in my domain system.

```
<html><head></head>
<body>

<?php
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.example.org:143}", "username", "password");

echo "<h1>Mailboxes</h1>\n";
$folders = imap_listmailbox($mbox, "{imap.example.org:143}", "*");

if ($folders == false) {
echo "Call failed<br />\n";
} else {
foreach ($folders as $val) {
    echo $val . "<br />\n";
}
}

echo "<h1>Headers in INBOX</h1>\n";
$headers = imap_headers($mbox);

if ($headers == false) {
echo "Call failed<br />\n";
} else {
foreach ($headers as $val) {
    echo $val . "<br />\n";
}
}

imap_close($mbox);
?>
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem you are facing is and what the desired output is compared to the one you are getting.  Please read this first [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I need to know how to get my domain all unseen mail using php or any other languages.

Comment: The way you are asking your question is basically asking someone to do all your work for you or point out to you some library or something of site. Which both fall under on of the flags and are not welcomed as questions on this site. If you wish for someone to help you out on this question. You will need to provide much more precise question and the problem. The answer: `this isn't working` or `I get an error` are not valid responses. But something like this is: `I want to do X and my result should be Y but I get Z` and provide the code you tried and someone will point out the problem than

Comment: why did you tag `java`? i doubt it is relevant here

Comment: I want to know to which way i can get it, if java has option to do this so that i tagged